# Is PellesC strictly-conforming to standard C99?

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-construction, c99, pelles-c

I have found in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C99 that Pelles C has full support for C99.
However I have doubts.

As probably you know, the GCC project has not yet reached full support for C99. The details in which GCC is conforming or not are very well documented. However, I cannot understand what exactly means that Pelles C is fully conforming.

Is it conforming for every computer and operating system?

For example, GCC (under command line option -std=c99) is compliant with ISO/IEC IEEE 60559 (floating point standard) if the hardware is perfectly compliant.
http://gcc.gnu.org/c99status.html

Is Pelles C concerned with this level of detail?
I don't feel sure about the claims that Pelles C is C99 conforming.

Comment: Note that 60559-compliance is not a prerequisite for C99-compliance.

Comment: “strictly-conforming” is a phrase that applies to programs, not compilers: C99 4:5 “A strictly conforming program shall use only those features of the language and library specified in this International Standard.”. A compiler can be “conforming” (4:6)

Answer (score 1):

According to [this article](http://www.smorgasbordet.com/pellesc/) and [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C99#Implementations), Pelles C has full support for C99 (and C11). So unless you have evidence showing that it doesn't, I think one can say it conforms the C99 standard.

As for the support for IEC 60559 floating-point arithmetic, note that it's only optional in C99 (and in C11):

> **C99 §6.10.8 Predefined macro names**
>
> The following macro names are conditionally defined by the implementation:
>
> `__STDC_IEC_559__` The integer constant 1, intended to indicate conformance to the
>   specifications in annex F (IEC 60559 floating-point arithmetic).
>
> `__STDC_IEC_559_COMPLEX__` The integer constant 1, intended to indicate adherence to the specifications in informative annex G (IEC 60559 compatible complex arithmetic).

Comment: Thank you YU Hao. Anyway, I'll follow searching more technical and detailed information, if it exists.